# Custom Setting in Validation Rule

Tags: validation-rule, customsetting

Does anyone know how I can use a custom setting list in a validation rule?  We have a custom setting list that contains State and Country names and abbreviations.  I would like to set up a validation rule that prevents a user from entering a State or country not in the list.  Is this possible, if so what is the syntax?

Answer (score 7):

The answer is NO - only hierarchical settings.

However, there is VLOOKUP formula function that can reference a custom object where your state and country names can exist. See [the zipcode example in the doc](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&language=en_US#VLOOKUP) for a template.