# How to use Custom Label in REGEX function in Validation Rule

Tags: validation-rule, regular-expressions, customlabel

I am able to use the regex formula string directly in the validation rule and its working fine when I tested it.

```
AND(
    CONTAINS(RecordType.Name, 'International_Lead'),
    !REGEX(Phone, '^(\\+)\\d{8,15}$')
)
```

Here is the reference that I got for above implementation 
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_regex.htm&type=5

But when I put the regex formula in the Custom Label, the validation rule outcome is different and I got a validation rule error.

```
Phone can only contain plus sign(+), numbers(0-9) and should be a valid phone number.
```

Validation Rule with Custom Label:

```
AND(
    CONTAINS(RecordType.Name, 'International_Lead'),
    !REGEX(Phone, $Label.International_Phone_Number_Regex)
)
```

Custom Label:

**Name**: International_Phone_Number_Regex

**Value**: `^(\\+)\\d{8,15}$`

Is it possible to use Custom Label in the REGEX function in Validation Rule?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only use `\\` to represent `\` inside of source code (Apex, JavaScript) and formulas (e.g. validation rules). When you're using a Custom Label, Custom Metadata, Static Resource, or other sources you might load as plain data, do not use the escape character, as it will be incorrectly interpreted. Your validation rule is effectively looking for something like `\+\d{8,15}` as a literal string to match, rather than the intended escapes. As Phil W says, you may want to consider using a Custom Metadata entry instead of a Custom Label, but keep in mind, either way, you don't use escape sequences for plain data, only for source code.

Answer (score 0):

Use of a custom label to hold configuration is an anti-pattern and an abuse of custom labels (unless you require a locale-specific value, but even then I would argue it isn't appropriate as there are few situations where validation should change based on the contextual user's locale).

You should consider using custom metadata or hierarchical custom settings instead. The latter is accessed via `$Setup.CustomSettingName__c.FieldName__c` while the former is accessed via `$CustomMetadata.CMTName__mdt.RecordName.FieldName__c` (as documented [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.custommetadatatypes_formula_fields.htm&type=5)).

You can also use `VLOOKUP` as discussed in [this Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/131472/50252) to use data from records, if that is appropriate.

Comment: hi Phil, yes agree with you, better to move this to custom setting. Thanks for the feedback!